# != All may be used inside SQL Statement only

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql

I have a procedure to loop through records from one table with a cursor then initate a insert statement into another table.

I am receiving this error in the If Statement "!= ALL"

```
If V_Item = V_Item_G
   And V_New_Part Is Null
   And (V_Delete_G Is Null or V_Delete_G != 'Y')
   And Status_G != ALL  ('KNOWN', 'NEW, 'UNKNOWN', 'SOLD')
THEN INSERT INTO PART 
   VALUES ( V_Item, V_New_Part);
```

--NOTE NOT IN DOES NOT WORK

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `And Status_G NOT IN ('KNOWN'...`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `!= All` use `Not In ('KNOWN', 'NEW, 'UNKNOWN', 'SOLD')`

Comment: Well NVM, NOT IN Is not returning the correct values on the insert!

Comment: When I manually troubleshoot, != ALL or != Any return the correct values I need to insert from a select statement, but when I use NOT IN inside the statement it does not insert the correct values.  If I comment out that line and execute the procedure it returns most of the correct values.

Comment: @user1307149, would you show your sample table and sample results that you want? update your question.